# Hadoop HDFS copy with wildcards?

Tags: hadoop, copy, hdfs

I want to copy a certain pattern of files from within hdfs to another location in the same hdfs cluster. The dfs shell does not seem to be able to handle this:

```
hadoop dfs -cp /tables/weblog/server=jeckle/webapp.log.1* /tables/tinylog/server=jeckle/
```

No error is returned: yet also no files are copied.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need use double quote with your path that contains wildcard, like this:

```
hdfs fs -cp "/path/to/foo*" /path/to/bar/
```

Comment: Curious - how can that work? The shell will expand the "*" before hds even sees it.  Did you mean *single* quote?

Comment: it doesn't matter about both quote. The quote just tell shell DO NOT expand the wildcard instead of as single parameter pass to hdfs command. I try both quote it does work.

Comment: Is this described somewhere in documentation?

Comment: @Marek This is a shell variable knowledge. Think of "/foo/bar/*" as one argument, or shell will try to expand wildcard(e.g.: '*', '?').

Comment: Right. I should thoroughly read your previous comment. If you had time you could move this explanation from comments to answer.

Comment: In Bash, double quotes will preserve literal value of characters except $~/ and maybe ! (depending on settings).  Single quotes preserves everything.  So if using * is causing expansion problems (prolly depending on what's in your cwd), either single or double quotes should work.  More here:  [https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, HDFS copy with wildcards is supported. Secondly, use of `hadoop dfs` is deprecated, you'd better use `hadoop fs` or `hdfs dfs` instead. If you're sure the operation was not successful (although it seems succeed), you could check out the log files of namenode to see what's wrong.

Comment: As stated in the OP, no files are copied using the given wildcard pattern. If you are going to state "wildcards are supported" please demonstrate.

Comment: because i just tried the same command as yours on my clusters and it works for both 2.1 and 0.23.9. Seriously, please check your namenode logs

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. This is what I get in my local VM running Hadoop 0.18.0. What version are you using? I can try on 1.2.1 also

```
hadoop-user@hadoop-desk:~$ hadoop fs -ls /user/hadoop-user/testcopy
hadoop-user@hadoop-desk:~$ hadoop dfs -cp /user/hadoop-user/input/*.txt /user/hadoop-user/testcopy/
hadoop-user@hadoop-desk:~$ hadoop fs -ls /user/hadoop-user/testcopy
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop-user supergroup         79 2014-01-06 04:35 /user/hadoop-user/testcopy/HelloWorld.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop-user supergroup        140 2014-01-06 04:35 /user/hadoop-user/testcopy/SampleData.txt
```

Comment: You are running very old version of hadoop.. but even so in this case it would not likely matter. I am on 1.2.1

Comment: Tried 1.2.1 and it work on that as well. However, I found this [link](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#Wildcard_characters_doesn.27t_work_correctly_in_FsShell.) Please check.

Answer (score 0):

**These both worked for me:**

```
~]$ hadoop fs -cp -f /user/cloudera/Dec_17_2017/cric* /user/cloudera/Dec_17_2017/Dec_18 
~]$ hadoop fs -cp -f "/user/cloudera/Dec_17_2017/cric*" /user/cloudera/Dec_17_2017/Dec_18
```

I thinks better way is that don't give double/single("/') quotes.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody wants to copy the files and folders from the current directory where the user is in the terminal, then

```
hdfs dfs -put ./
```