# Hadoop fs -rm with regular expression

Tags: regex, hadoop, hdfs, rm

I have a table with 9k partitions, of which I would like to delete about 1200 (which represents 3 days)
I would like to combine the `hadoop fs -rm` and regular expressions for these 3 days, something like `pr_load_time=2017070([1-4])(\d+)` .

The partitions look like this (I want to match only the first two here)

```
pr_load_time=20170701000317
pr_load_time=20170704133602
pr_load_time=20170705000317
pr_load_time=20170706133602
```

Is something like this possible? I was thinking about matching the partitions with awk and use xargs, but this seems to be really slow approach to delete such a big number of files.

Comment: If this is something that you need only once, run 4 wildcard deletions: `hadoop fs -rm "/path/pr_load_time=20170701*"`, ...`"...0702*"`..., etc. Else, you would likely need to delete them individually using xargs or similar commands

Comment: @Jedi yes, I just need to do it once. So If I want to delete everything for 4th of July, I just start with 20170704* and the wildcard will take care about everything after that "04"?

Comment: Yes. You can do a dry run using `ls` instead of `rm`. You would [need double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32738462).

Answer (score 2):

I guess above comment would solve your problem however you could try below in case

```
/hdfs path/pr_load_time={20170701000317,20170704133602,20170705000317,..}
```

or something like this

```
/hdfs path/pr_load_time=201707{01000317,04133602,05000317,..}
```

this can combine different pattern in single command

/hdfs path/pr_load_time=201707{01*,04*,05*,..}