# Hadoop - How to remove files by name

Tags: hadoop

Is there a command in hadoop to remove files starting with ab ? The files can occur in sub-directories and the operation should be recursive.
Something similar to the below :

```
Hadoop fs -rmr /mydir/ab*
```

Comment: Did you tried your example command? It will work i think.

Comment: Yes. I get an error message 'No such file or directory'

Comment: Do you have "mydir" in root directory? Note: HDFS directories/files are case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like below,

```
hadoop fs -rmr "/mydir/ab*"
```

You need to use double quotes for the path which contains wildcard.

**References:**

[Hadoop HDFS copy with wildcards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938661/hadoop-hdfs-copy-with-wildcards/32738462#32738462)

[Hadoop fs -rm with regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536017/hadoop-fs-rm-with-regular-expression)

Comment: The name of the file is single letter. In this case it is D. Getting the same error.

Comment: D* won't delete a file named 'D'. * means there should be some character next to D.

Comment: In this case, you can run two commands

hadoop fs -rmr "/mydir/D" & hadoop fs -rmr "/mydir/D*"