# Hadoop fs test command with wildcard characters

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to check if file following a pattern exists on a hdfs path. I am trying with the below command:

`hadoop fs -test -e  /user/foo/bar/abc*`

But its throwing error:

```
test: `/user/foo/bar/abc*': No such file or directory
```

Per the below question I tried using both double quotes & single quotes but still same issue:
[Hadoop HDFS copy with wildcards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938661/hadoop-hdfs-copy-with-wildcards/32738462)

```
hadoop fs -test -e  "/user/foo/bar/abc*"
test: `/user/foo/bar/abc*': No such file or directory
hadoop fs -test -e  '/user/foo/bar/abc*'
test: `/user/foo/bar/abc*': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to quote (double quotes) the literal or path in the case which has any wildcards or requires expansion.

Try this...
`hadoop fs -test -e  "/user/foo/bar/abc*"`

Comment: This is not the correct use of the command. If you want to see whether the file exists why would you not just use the filename with full URI instead of wildcard?